# How to get data from multiple URL's using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have 3 API endpoints and I have made a search box where user inputs search term. After typing in the search term in search box all the data from API endpoint should return it.

API endpoints:

```
localhost:5000/mydata1/search/q="searchterm"

localhost:5000/mydata2/search/q="searchterm

localhost:5000/mydata3/search/q="searchterm"
```

Now above our 3 API endpoints. When I type in some search term in search box it should display all the data from API endpoints. 
As I am new to ReactJS I want to ask to get the data (JSON response) from API endpoints do I need to call `fetch()` on each URL's to get the data or is there some other efficient way to do it.

Comment: `React` has nothing to do with fetch calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bluebirds Promise.all. [Documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html). This will wait for any number of calls to finish before providing a response object.

Comment: Thank You I got it.